# Recipe ideas for fresh hops give to me

Tags: hops

[image: drying hops]My friend gave me some fresh hops from his plants he harvested this past weekend. They are currently drying. The only problem is that he mixed three varieties in one bag. He wrote onto the bag it mighht make a good pilsner. He said it was roughly 40% cascade 40% Willamette and 20%  East Kent golds.

Ive been brewing about 4 years and have never made a pilsner with anything but saaz.

I brew 5G batches. I would think they soak up a lot of wort.

Any ideas on recipes or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I get fresh hops- I just often just use them as dry hop. Depending on the year, conditions, cross-pollination, etc they won't always exactly mimic hop characters that you're used to in specific varietals. Also ..once dried you lose a ton of your mass. Since they've never been packed tight- it usually looks like a lot more hops than actually is there by weight (not sure if there's tons and tons of them off-camera).

What you should use them for really depends on their character. Rub a few cones and smell them and see what they're like..and then use it in an appropriate beer.